# In Swiftui on Macos is it possible to use .keyboardshortcut in a subview?

Tags: swiftui, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been building a large app for Macos (entirely in SwiftUI) that has a sidebar which is always visible, and a main screen where the work gets done.
Using the .keyboardshortcut modifier on buttons on the sidebar works beautifully, but I have not been able to get the shortcuts to fire from buttons in the ContentView.
Any suggestions?
A very simple example demonstrating the problem:

```
let days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(days, id:\.self) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    Text(item)
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<7, id:\.self) { i in
                            Text("Hour" + String(i))
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    print("tap")
                                }
                                .keyboardShortcut("l")
                        }//foreach
                    }//hstack
                } label: {
                    Text(item)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        Text("Select an item")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can add a keyboard shortcut to a text view. If you change the text to a button and add a listener, it will fire when holding command and pressing the assigned letter.

But here's the second problem: You're assigning the same keyboard shortcut to multiple hours. Each hour would need its own shortcut, but of course there are more potential hours than numbers on a keyboard.

In your example there are only six hours represented, so you could assign 1-6 to each hour, though this will only work for a very limited number of hours displayed on screen at one time.

```
Button("Hour" + String(i)) {
    print("tapped index ", i)
}
.buttonStyle(.borderless)
.keyboardShortcut(KeyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent(Character(String(i)))))
// will only work up to 9, then you run out of physical keys
```

Comment: Thanks-- yes, I made all the text trigger the same action just to demonstrate the problem.
The workaround (suggested in various places) is to put buttons in a ZStack on the Sidebar and hide them behind other things (in my case a rounded rectangle) so they will not be triggered by clicking. 
But it is still annoying because I have to write the routines twice and hiding buttons can cause layout problems.

Comment: But actually you can attach a shortcut to a text (or to any view for that matter) when it has a .onTapGesture, I use this all the time.

Comment: Adding .allowsHitTesting(false) to a button will prevent it from being clicked but the key shortcuts will remain intact.